# Consulta where Datatables

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un fetch para mostrar datos a una Datatable y quiero que me traiga información desde MySQL filtrado por un id-

El problema está en que me sigue mostrando toda la información.

La consulta la armo con:

```
'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 10'
```

y concateno esto por cada valor que tengo:

```
'AND first_name LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" 
 OR last_name LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%"'
```

---

Lo que finalmente intento es que llegue una variable POST (pero para hacer pruebas estoy poniendo un numero con un id).

El código del fetch:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "testing");
$columns = array(
    'first_name',
    'last_name'
);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 10";

if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) {
    $query .= '
    AND first_name LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" 
    OR last_name LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" 
    ';
}

if (isset($_POST["order"])) {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY ' . $columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']] . ' 
     ' . $_POST['order']['0']['dir'] . ' 
     ';
} else {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if ($_POST["length"] != -1) {
    $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sub_array   = array();
    $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-
     id="' . $row["id"] . '" data-column="first_name">' . $row["first_name"] . '</div>';
    $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-
     id="' . $row["id"] . '" data-column="last_name">' . $row["last_name"] . '</div>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-
     danger btn-xs delete" id="' . $row["id"] . '">Delete</button>';
    $data[]      = $sub_array;
}

function get_all_data($connect)
{
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$output = array(
    "draw" => intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal" => get_all_data($connect),
    "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
    "data" => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Comment: fijate que este codigo tiene problemas por donde lo mires. Primero estas concatenando partes de un sql, sin embargo no hay un solo espacio dentro de todos los strings, por lo cual el query podria llegar a quedar como SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 10ORDER BY id DESC; o sea, anda de milagro. o no anda y no lo estas aclarando. o tiene algun otro problema mas. Lo mejor que podes haces es imprimir por pantalla con un echo tu variable query, y ver si realmente ese query en la BD anda bien.

Comment: Por ahí estaba parte de la solución, muchas gracias @gbianchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás el problema esté en los argumentos del WHERE y se está ejecutando siempre el last_name LIKE "". Prueba adicionar paréntesis.

`$query .= '
AND ( first_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR last_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ) 
';`

Comment: Gracias @Roberto, muchas gracias faltaban esos benditos paréntesis.

Comment: Más cuidado para la próxima. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo utilizar una librería PHP que proveen ellos llamada ssp.php o tal como lo muestra éste enlace: [enlace](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)   la librería llamada "server_processing.php". Con ella tienes todos los parámetros POST ya contemplados y luego "modificas" a tu gusto el armado de las sentencias SQL.

Comment: Excelente dato, voy a consultarla. Gracias